# How to check text file it contains delimiter at the end or not?if it is there how to remove it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

actually i have text file with columns and rows colsep is "'" and row sep is "/"
and my text file is sfsf'fsfsdf'sdfsdf/dfsdf'sfsf'sfsfs/

if my text file contains "/" at the end of the file how to check and remove it it is there

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)

```
string str = File.ReadAllText(path);
str = str.TrimEnd('/');
```

Comment: i wanted check at the end of the file delimiter is there or not

Comment: TrimEnd will check if the delimiter is there and will remove it, if the delimiter is not there, then it will not do anything. If you want to make sure that the string ends with a character, use [EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
string fileString = = File.ReadAllText(your file path);
if(fileString[fileString.Length-1].Equals('/'))
{
//your code here;
}
```

OR you can use:

```
 if(fileString.EndsWith('/'))
{
//yourcode
}
```

We can check individual characters in string using their index as we all know that:

```
 string is the sequence of characters
```

this will solve your problem to check last character in file.

Comment: [`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) would be much easier here (not least by clearly stating what you are doing).

Comment: Well I have checked the character at last index of string as per the question.
And yes we can use that too. Well I doesn't know about that function.